# Facebook C# SDK , .NET MVC , passing parameters to ActionResults with facebook app URL

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, facebook-c#-sdk, asp.net-mvc-routing

I been working on a .NET MVC / Azure / SQL Azure / Facebook app using the facebook c# sdk.

Took a while but I seem to have it logging users in, im able to capture the relevant data needed to use the app.

Without going into what the app is ,  a user goes through a 3 step process , once the user gets to the end of the process I fire off some generated data to twitter api to post a tweet and also generate a shortened url using the Bit.ly api.

I then give the user the option to post to their facebook wall.  I can get the app posting with the right data to the users wall ok.

The problem I face is the URL with the id on the end that is suppose to take any person who clicks it to a partial view displaying relevant data to the id on the URL.

URL looks like this http: //apps.facebook.com/myapp/?id=1
I have two  public ActionResult Index(string id) , one with a parameter(POST) & one without(GET)

`

```
[Authorize]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to The My App Website!";
    ViewData["id"] = "null";
    try
    {
    var facebookId = long.Parse(User.Identity.Name);
    var user = InMemoryUserStore.Get(facebookId);
    var client = new FacebookClient(user.AccessToken);
    dynamic me = client.Get("me");
    ViewData["accessToken"] = user.AccessToken.ToString();
    ViewData["FirstName"] = me.first_name;
    ViewData["LastName"] = me.last_name;
    ViewData["Email"] = me.email;
    ViewData["uid"] = facebookId.ToString();


   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
   throw;
   }

    return View();

}
```

`

```
    [Authorize]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to My App!";
        ViewData["id"] = id;

        try
        {
            var facebookId = long.Parse(User.Identity.Name);
            var user = InMemoryUserStore.Get(facebookId);
            var client = new FacebookClient(user.AccessToken);
            dynamic me = client.Get("me");
            ViewData["accessToken"] = user.AccessToken.ToString();
            ViewData["FirstName"] = me.first_name;
            ViewData["LastName"] = me.last_name;
            ViewData["Email"] = me.email;
            ViewData["uid"] = facebookId.ToString();


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           throw;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

On the index page using JQuery I do this,

'

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var str = "@ViewBag.id";

if(str != "null" || str != null){

                $('#imgLoading').css("display", "inline");
                $('#side').css('display', 'none');
                $('#contentDiv').html("");
                $.get('home/GetUniqueView/?id=' + str, function (data6) {

                $('#contentDiv').html(data6);
                $('#imgLoading').css("display", "none");

                });

    }else{


    }

});
```

The problem is passing parameters to the actionresult from the facebook canvas

This facebook app url 
http: //apps.facebook.com/myapp/  << this would be route /Home/Index

maps to something like this
http: //myapp.cloudapp.net/    << this would be route /Home/Index

so im assuming http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/?id=1 maps to http: //myapp.cloudapp.net/?id=1

in my Global.asax page I have

`

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Can anyone help me or advise on passing parameters to MVC Controller Action Results with the Facebook canvas url's & facebook c# sdk.

Its important for my app to be able to direct users to a specific view/partial view based on passed id.

Am I going about this the right way, can anyone see a flaw in my approach and is their something im missing or not doing.

best regards

Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I going about this the right way, can anyone see a flaw in my
>   approach and is their something im missing or not doing.

You seem to be attempting to perform an AJAX request from `http://apps.facebook.com/myapp` to `http://myapp.cloudapp.net/` which obviously is impossible due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction built-in browsers. It basically prevents you from sending cross domain AJAX requests. Here's a [guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) which covers some possible workarounds.

Comment: Ok ,so if i send them to http: //myapp.cloudapp.net/?id=1

how would i get the user back to the app within facebook any ideas,

Comment: At least for the most part Darin , you have answered the qu estion. 

I will think about the solution a little longer for a better solution,  I suppose directing the user out side of facebook is not so bad.  I will try a few more things.

Thanks

Comment: I finally solved it, 

The issue was not what you discussed above, although it did lead me to finding what the problem was. 

The ajax call was on the same domain, 

`


            $.get('/Home/GetUniqueView/?id=' + str, function(data6){
                
                $('#contentDiv').html(data6);
                $('#imgLoading').css("display", "none");

            });


Note the URL compared to the 1st one, the .NET MVC route was missing the 1st forward slash "/" 

Notw it is behaving as I expected it to,

Comment: both 

http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/?id=1

and

http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/Home/Index/?id=1 

work